# Windows 10 laptop sound problems

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, sound-card, system-sounds

I have had this laptop (Windows 10 pro Lenovo IdeaPad L340 Gaming - core i7 9th generation) for about 2 years now. But lately I've been experiencing sound problems (no sound at all coming out of my speakers).

I tried reinstalling my drivers again which didn't work. Updating them didn't work either. Even putting in headphones (wired) doesn't work. However, when I have a Bluetooth device or a device connected from an HDMI, the sound comes out.

I've tried so many solutions yet none helped. When I open up my speakers properties it says "this device is working properly" but when I hit 'test tone' it gives an error can't play sound. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can try removing the sound device via the Device Manager console, then rebooting the computer. This will cause Windows to go through a full set up on the “newly detected” hardware.

Comment: @JG7 i tried doing that and didnt work

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the Realtek drivers. It happens to me too and I resolved it by ROLLBACK driver's a couple of versions. Actually, Windows update updates to latest version which broke my sound a few times. So, try rollback sound driver and let me know.

Comment: the roll back button is disabled for me